RIP James Earl Jones, a voice that will live forever

James Earl Jones, the prolific film, TV and theater actor whose resonant, unmistakable baritone was most widely known as the voice of “Star Wars” villain Darth Vader, died Monday morning at his home in Dutchess County, N.Y., his rep confirmed to Variety. He was 93.

A voice that will be forever known in our community as one the best villains to ever grace a franchise.  Over 60 years of lending his imposing stature and voice to rolls across all genres and roles; kings (human and lion), admirals, baseball legends, and many others.
His voice has unified at least 3 generations of fans of Star Wars, and I think I speak for all of us when saying that he will be missed, but that his voice will last forever in the character he brought to life.
Rest in peace, James. Our thoughts and prayers go out to your friends and family. May the Force be with you!

I was hunting for a good quote to put in the title, but you beat me to it. :D  (BTW, should it come that I chance to write it, I know exactly what I would title Lucas' in-memoriam post.)

Nooooo

Note: typo "rolls" => "roles", unless there's a wordplay I am missing.

The guy was an amazing actor, not just for his voice.  He made saying the alphabet into an event.




While it's nice that he gets so much appreciation, it's also a bit odd that among all the amazing roles he played, he tends to get reduced to a mere voice over gig a lot.

The voiceovers do belie how many major roles he had in acting, but there's no denying his voice was both iconic and very prone to narrative. David Letterman often had him reading funny things with a deadpan expression, as this montage shows



